# calling jsp page from within iframe

Tags: jsp, struts

I have a question like when i call the jsp page from within iframe, is the struts method get called first and then the action class renders the jsp page or the jsp page get called directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you directly call the JSP page and you do not have any filters (proxies) defined which may modify or reroute the request, then your JSP gets called directly.